# Is it possible to use the ~ and + selector at the same time?

Tags: html, css

For demo purposes say I have html like:

```
<input type="checkbox" id='hi'>
<label for="hi"> hi </label>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

and corresponding CSS as

```
ul {
  display:none;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked ~ul{
  display:inline-block;
  background-color:red;
}

input[type='checkbox']:checked +label {
  background-color:red;
}
```

The idea is, when the checkbox is checked, I want the label with text 'hi' to have a background color of red and also to display a ul with a background-color of red.

As shown above, I needed to duplicate code to have a ~ul and +label after each :checked

Am curious to know whether or not this can be combined i.e. only using :checked once in above instead of twice, in any manner?

Comment: Not in CSS, but in LESS you could do `input:checked { &~ul { ... } &+label { ... } }`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol LESS renders to CSS so then there is a way to do it in CSS by that logic. But to me CSS can't detect the "hi" string but JavaScript can.

Comment: @NathanielFlick: The CSS in the question works. They’re asking about making it less repetitive.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol the LESS won't make it any less repetitive...

Comment: @NathanielFlick: Except it does, in exactly the way the question asked for, the way @​Niet showed it.

Comment: @Ry- once the LESS is rendered it becomes the same CSS though. input:checked ~ ul {
  color: Red;
}
input:checked + label {
  color: Blue;
}

Comment: @NathanielFlick Right, but at least on the programming side it's less repetitive, and (arguably) clearer since there's structure to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, when you need to apply different properties to different selectors, there’s no way to do it in one rule in plain CSS. This is why people sometimes choose to use languages that compile to CSS, like Sass or Less.

```
input[type='checkbox']:checked {
    & ~ ul, & + label {
        background-color: red;
    }

    & ~ ul {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

The main good alternative is to change your HTML structure so the selectors are more natural.